# Unable to click/choose dropdown options in mobile screen, using react select dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropdown, responsive, react-select

I'm using react select dropdown, which works well in desktop mode in selecting/deselecting options but as soon as I switch to responsive screen the options are visible but as I try clicking the dropdown/ try selecting an option it closes and I'm unable to select(ps: hideSelectedOptions={false} and closeMenuOnSelect={false}-it works fine on desktop but having issues with responsive screen)

[code for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stgkB.png)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is still an issue for you but I was experiencing this issue as well. For context I was embedding react-select dropdowns into a custom header component for react-datepicker. The dropowns control the year and month selection.

On desktop everything worked but on mobile/responsive screen I was experiencing the exact same issue you describe here.

I use portaling for react-select dropdowns more often than not:

```
menuPortalTarget={document.body}
```

This seemingly was the principal cause of the issue because once this is removed I could select options but I was getting UI issues.

So my solution was to use [react-device-detect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-device-detect) here.

```
menuPortalTarget={isMobile ? null : document.body}
```

To address the UI issues I simply had to add `position: absolute;` to the react-select menu container.

Everything seems to work as expected now so hopefully this might help anyone who experiences a similar issue going forward.